# Add start and Stop Button for code in Python Using tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to add **Start and Stop Button** for my code using **tkinter**
I just want that when I click on **start Button**  for **scheduler.start()** the code will run
and when I click on **stop button**  for **scheduler.shutdown()** code will stop
It is a **Python 2.7** version but don't worry I just need the idea for this code that how it'll run
here is my code:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

    logging.basicConfig(filename='read.log', level=logging.INFO)
    logging.getLogger('apscheduler').setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()

    scheduler.add_job(calstk, 'interval', seconds=20)
  #  scheduler.add_job(calmrp, 'interval', seconds=10)
   # scheduler.add_job(caldisc, 'interval', seconds=15)



    # leave space only for understanding for which I need to add **start Button**

    scheduler.start()  # for this scheduler.start()



    print('Press Ctrl+{0} to exit'.format('Break' if os.name == 'nt' else 'C'))

    try:
       # stock = calstk()
        #print stock
        print '************************************************************************************'
        # This is here to simulate application activity (which keeps the main thread alive).
        while True:
            time.sleep(10)
    except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
        # Not strictly necessary if daemonic mode is enabled but should be done if possible
        pass



    # leave space only for understanding for which I need to add **Stop Button**
scheduler.shutdown()
# for this scheduler.shutdown()
```

I want to add a start  button for **scheduler.start()**  
and stop Button for **scheduler.shutdown()** .
I really need this code I almost build my project and I only need these two Button to handle my project.

Answer (score 2):

```
import tkinter as tk
win = tk.Tk()
top = tk.Frame(win, padx = 20, pady = 20)
b1 = tk.Button(top, text='Start', padx = 10, pady = 10, command=scheduler.start)
b2 = tk.Button(top, text='Stop', padx = 10, pady = 10, command=scheduler.shutdown)
b1.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
b2.pack(side=tk.RIGHT)
top.pack()
win.mainloop()
```

This is how you can add buttons.

Comment: Brother, I didn't know about Tkinter if you give me a solution it's good for me. Thanks

Comment: If your question has been answered mark the answer. So that others can know that the query is resolved